# Getting form object values in a script

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

If you have this kind of form attribute in Spring:

```
<form:select path="form_object.id" items="${objects}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="description">
```

How can you pass the id (type is int) value to script?

```
$("#form_object").change(function(){
 alert($(this.val));
```

this.val returns nothing. I need to posses the id value of selected item.

Answer (score 0):

You've written:

`alert($(this.val));`

instead, try:

`alert($(this).val());`

the `.val` property of `this` is probably undefined, so when you get the jQuery selector `undefined`, you get undefined back from jQuery.

Maybe I'm misreading this? If you just need the id of an `<input>`, use view-source or Chrome's right click -> inspect element feature to find the id.

Comment: Nope. If I put just the object in select's path, I get the alert box with undefined, but this way nothing happens.

Comment: Found a solution! I had to fix the path in parent select list.